# PyQt5 crashing with threading and progress bar

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I have a progress bar that is controlled by a start stop button. The progress bar fills up using a thread. However, whenever I run the program it crashes at random times (different time each time program is run).

```
class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.fill_thread = None
```

Thread for filling progress bar. I have tried using both time.sleep and QThread.msleep.

```
def fill_bar(self):
    while not self.stop_fill and self.completed < 100:
        self.completed += 0.5
        QThread.msleep(100)
        self.chargeprog.setValue(self.completed)
```

Buttons that alternate between start and stop that call the thread

```
def charging(self):
    if self.chargebtn.text() == 'Start':
        self.chargebtn.setText('Stop')
        self.chargebtn.setStyleSheet('background-color:red')
        self.fill_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.fill_bar)
        self.stop_fill = False
        self.fill_thread.start()
    else:
        self.stop_fill = True
        self.fill_thread.join()
        self.chargebtn.setText('Start')
        self.chargebtn.setStyleSheet('background-color:limegreen')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> window.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'window.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 150, 118, 23))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 18))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

> test.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread,pyqtSignal
from window import Ui_MainWindow

class CThread(QThread):
    valueChanged = pyqtSignal([int])
    def __init__(self,value):
        super().__init__()
        self.stop_fill = False
        self.completed = value

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_fill and self.completed < 100:
            self.completed += 0.5
            self.sleep(1)
            self.valueChanged.emit(self.completed)

class Window(QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super().setupUi(self)
        self.fill_thread = None
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.charging)

    def charging(self):
        if self.pushButton.text() == 'Start':
            self.pushButton.setText('Stop')
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background-color:red')
            print(self.progressBar.value())
            self.fill_thread = CThread(self.progressBar.value())
            self.fill_thread.valueChanged.connect(self.progressBar.setValue)
            self.fill_thread.start()
        else:
            if self.fill_thread != None:
                self.fill_thread.disconnect() # event unbind
                self.fill_thread.stop_fill = True
                self.fill_thread.wait()
                self.fill_thread.quit()
                print(self.fill_thread.isRunning())
            self.pushButton.setText('Start')
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet('background-color:limegreen')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you want communicate between multi-threads, you can try signal/slots.